# Payment failed due to low funds. How to avoid negative schufa score

Tags: germany

I payed at a supermarket in Germany for amount of 55.21 EUR with my debit card. Due to low funds (my bad did not check my account) the transaction failed when the bank tried to get the money from my account the next day and the money was not debitied. I want to avoid negative SCHUFA scre and pay the supermarket. How do I do that? My german is not good enough to deal with the bank.
Any help is appriciated.
[image]

Comment: You might be better asking on https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How about going to the supermarket with cash in hand?

Comment: You need to contact a supermarket yourself (is it their web site? https://www.v-markt.de/kontakt), or wait for letter from them.